# Why is the Bishopric of Canterbury located in London?

Tags: london

As far as I understand the seat used to be in Canterbury and then was transferred to London but kept the title. Is that true and when did this happen?

Comment: The [Province of Canterbury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Province_of_Canterbury#mediaviewer/File:Dioceses_of_the_CofE.png) contains London; it isn't "in London". The Archbishop of Canterbury maintains a residence, the [Old Palace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Palace,_Canterbury), in Canterbury.

Comment: London is in the ecclesiastical "Province of Canterbury", but it is not in the diocese of Canterbury. The Archbishop of Canterbury has, as bishop, no authority in London, but as primate of the Church of England he is primus inter pares among the Anglican bishops.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks. Actually I found the answer I was looking for.

http://www.archbishopofcanterbury.org/pages/the-history-of-lambeth-palace.html

Comment: +1 to what semaphore said, although it seems that this user no longer cares about us :(

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine didn't even post it with the same account, I wouldn't hold my breath… that being said, _at least_ he _did_ follow up, however in this invalid way. Still better than what some others do.